# Why in Fat arrow functions arguments object is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

If we print the output of arguments variable inside a normal function:

```
var func = function() { console.log(arguments); }
func();
```

The result is an object which contains information about the context (parameter values, scope , functionLocation...)

But if we reproduce the same function with fat arrow, we will never get argument declared:

```
var func = () => { console.log(arguments); }
func();

// arguments is not defined
```

Can anyone explain how can we get the context data from arrow functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "context data"?

Comment: callee, caller and length. They are three useful properties for knowing where i'm called from for example.

Comment: Sorry for create duplicated question, didn't see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own **this**, **arguments**, **super**, or **new.target**. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.